# Restlet: can I have two Get functions routed to the same Resource class?

Tags: resources, get, restlet

I have a resource called "Item" having the following fields :

- Id
- Name
- Description

I want the user to be able to Get Items from the database whether by specifying the id or name.
eg, if I have this entry in the database  : (1,House, this is a House) corresponding to (id,name,description), then if the user send a Get request specifying that

- id=1

or

- name="table"

this should return the entry : (1,Table, this is a table).
The question is, can I do this in restlet ?
can I have the router routing /Item/{itemId}  and /Item/{itemName} routed to the same ItemResource class ? in this case, should I have two implementations for the getrepresentation function ?

Comment: I do not think that you want that kind of undefined semantics implemented. What should a uri `/Item/foo` match?! To a name or an id?

Answer (score 0):

You can route /Item/{itemId} and /Item/{itemName} to the same resource class, but as the commenter wrote (nearly a year ago!), you run the risk of ambiguity if the id and name namespaces aren't disjoint. A better design would be to have two resources:

```
/Item?name=MyName
/Item/1234
```

The first of these would be search resource that returns all items with name MyName. The second would simply look up the unique item 1234.

You could implement this with one resource class, but it would look neater as two separate resource classes (possibly with a common abstract superclass).